# How to correctly hook WSARecv in IE11

Tags: sockets, tcp, internet-explorer-11, hook, apimonitor

I'm currently working on a project which requires to hook TCP send and recv API in IE to monitor the TCP data. It works fine on IE9 and IE10. But it stop working on IE11. After some research, I found IE11 uses WSASend and WSARecv to send and receive data. So I decided to hook WSASend and WSARecv.

WSARecv is an overlapped operation. There are 3 ways to get the result of overlapped operations. When overlapped operations are used, they either have an associated event, a completion routine, or are associated with an I/O Completion port. 
I checked the overlapped structure when IE11 calls WSARec and found both event and completion routine are NULL, so I assume IE11 uses IO completion port to get the result of the overlapped operations.

The problem is GetQueuedCompletionStatus or GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx is never called by IE11. I use API monitor or hook those 2 functions directly and never see those 2 functions are called. I don't know if IE11 uses a different sets of APIs to get the result of WSARec. 
I wonder if anyone has encounter the similar problem. Which API should I hook? If there is an alternative way to achieve the same goal. Basically what I want to do is monitor TCP data in IE11.

Comment: Sounds like you're writing spyware....

Comment: Actually it is not a spyware. I'm monitoring TCP data to generate log information, for example, SSL connection count. I can not do it on HTTP level so I have to do it on TCP level...

Answer (score 1):

you can set a breakpoint in ntdll!**NtDeviceIoControlFile**, which all socket APIs are finally routed to, so you can know which one is used.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I try to hook NtDeviceIoControlFile and print out the Event and ApcRoutine parameters for AFD_RECV. The log shows all the ApcRoutine is null and about 80% of the Event paramter are set to null. I still don't understand how the result is being retrieved if both Event and ApcRoutine are null.

Comment: IE11 use WSARecv as synchronous call in my test. checkout my tool in github: https://github.com/xwlan/dprobe, which include a socket filter to capture all socket calls.

Comment: https://repositum.tuwien.at/bitstream/20.500.12708/12472/2/Petritsch%20Helmut%20-%202007%20-%20Understanding%20and%20replaying%20network%20traffic%20in%20Windows...pdf

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook [CreateThreadpoolIo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to filter the winsock extension functions like WSARecvMsg, WSASendMsg, for this you need to hook the  WSAIoctl & replace the extension function pointer